# Find the absolute maximum and minimum value of $f$

Tags: calculus

I have to find the absolute maximum and minimum value of $$f(x, y)=\sin x+\cos y$$ on the rectangle $[0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$.

I have done the following:

$$\nabla f=(\cos x, -\sin y)$$

$$\nabla f=0 \Rightarrow \cos x=0 \text{ and } -\sin y=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2} \text{ and } y=0, \pi, 2\pi$$

The critical points are $$\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, 0\right ), \left (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right ), \left (\frac{\pi}{2}, 2 \pi\right ), \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 0\right ), \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, \pi\right ), \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi\right )$$

The second derivatives are:

$$\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}=-\sin x \ \ ,\ \  \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y^2}}=-\cos y \ \ ,\ \  \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}=0$$

- $$\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, 0\right ): \ \  \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, 0\right )=-1<0$$
- $$\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right ): \ \  \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right )=-1<0$$
- $$\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, 2 \pi\right ): \ \ \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, 2 \pi\right )=-1<0$$
- $$\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 0\right ): \ \ \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}=1>0 \\ D=(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}})(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y^2}})-(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}})^2=-1<0$$
- $$\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, \pi\right ): \ \ \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, \pi\right )=1>0 \\ D=(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}})(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y^2}})-(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}})^2=1>0 \Rightarrow \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, \pi\right ) \text{ is a local minima } $$
- $$\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi\right ): \ \ \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi\right )=1>0 \\ D=(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}})(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y^2}})-(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}})^2=1>0 \Rightarrow \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 0\right ) \text{ is a local minima }$$

That means that the minimum value of $f$ is $$f\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 0\right )=f\left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi\right )=0$$

Is this correct??

$$$$

**EDIT1**:

We have to do the following steps:

1. Find all the critical points of $f$ in $U$.
2. Find the critical points of $f$, when we look at it as a function that is defined only at $\partial U$.
3. Calculate the value of $f$ at all the critical points.
4. Compare all these values and pick the greatest one and the smallest one.

$U$ is the open rectangle. How can we do the second step?

$$$$

**EDIT2:**

First step:

$$\nabla f=(\cos x, -\sin y)$$

$U=(0, 2 \pi ) \times(0, 2\pi)$

$$\nabla f=0 \Rightarrow \cos x=0 \text{ and } -\sin y=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2} \text{ and } y= \pi$$

The critical points in $U$ are $$\left (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\right ), \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}, \pi\right )$$

Second step:

Do we suppose that $x$ and $y$ can take only the values $0$ and $2 \pi$??

---

I have to find the absolute maximum and minimum value of $$f(x, y)=xy$$ on the rectangle $[-1, 1] \times [-1, 1]$.

I have done the following:

We have to do the following steps:

1. Find all the critical points of $f$ in $U=(-1, 1) \times (-1, 1)$.
2. Find the critical points of $f$, when we look at it as a function that is defined only at $\partial U$.
3. Calculate the value of $f$ at all the critical points.
4. Compare all these values and pick the greatest one and the smallest one.

**First step**:

$$\nabla f=(y, x)$$

$$\nabla f=0 \Rightarrow y=0 \text{ and } x=0$$

The only critical point in $U$ is $$(0, 0)$$

**Second step**:

$\partial U=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ with
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=&\left\{ (x,-1):-1\leq x\leq 1 \right\}  \\
B &=&\left\{ (1 ,y):-1\leq y\leq 1 \right\}  \\
C &=&\left\{ (x,1 ):-1\leq x\leq 1 \right\}  \\
D &=&\left\{ (-1,y):-1\leq y\leq 1 \right\} .
\end{eqnarray*}

$$A: f(x, -1)=-x=g(x) \\ g'(x)=0 \Rightarrow -1=0$$ 
$$B: f(1, y)=y=g(y) \\ g'(y)=0 \Rightarrow 1=0$$ 
$$C: f(x, 1)=x=g(x) \\ g'(x)=0 \Rightarrow 1=0$$ 
$$D: f(-1, y)=-y=g(y) \\ g'(y)=0 \Rightarrow -1=0$$ 
That means that there are no critical points on the boundary $\partial{U}$.

**Third step**:

The value of $f$ at the critical point $(0, 0)$ is $f(0, 0)=0$.

Is it correct so far??

**Forth step**:

How can $f$ have an absolute maximum and minimum value if there is only one critical point?? Or have I done something wrong??

Comment: In this particular case, can it not be done by inspection, $2$ and $-2$?

Comment: If a point is a minimum or maximum of a $C^{\infty}$ function, it is either as above or at the boundary of the closed region. That is, you still have to check for the extrema of $f(0,x)$, $f(2\pi,x)$, ...

Comment: For the minimum, look at $x=3\pi/2$, $y=\pi$. We cannot do better (worse?) since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are always $\ge -1$.

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ vary independently of each other, just pick the value of $x$ and the value of $y$ that make both sines equal to $-1$.  A sine is never less than $-1$ (unless you bring in imaginary numbers, and we're not doing that we we talk about $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$), so that is the absolute minimum.  You don't need derivatives to solve this.

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit part of my initial post??

Comment: Mary, something's gone wrong when you differentiated? $\partial^2f/\partial x^2=-\sin x$ and  $\partial^2f/\partial y^2=-\cos y$, and the mixed derivative vanishes everywhere. That sign error ruins the remaining parts. Agree with André in that the solution should stick out, local maximum values are $=2$, and minima $=-2$. IMO the exercise is about reaching the same conclusion with the Hessian (or whatever you call the test involving the 2nd partial derivatives).

Answer (score 2):

i am going to offer a more intuitive approach to this problem.

let f(x)=sin(x) on closed interval [0,2pi], then max f(x) = 1 at x = pi/2

similarly, let f(x)=cos(x) on closed interval [0,2pi], then max f(x) = 1 at x = 0 and 2pi

now consider f(x,y)=sin(x)+cos(y).  now is not apparent that max f(x,y) must equal 2 at (pi/2, 0), (pi/2, 2pi).

so there are two local maxima on closed interval [0,2pi], all of which give f(x,y)=2

similarly, sin(x) = -1 on closed interval [0,2pi] for x = 3/2pi.
cos(x) = -1 on [0,2pi] for x = pi

thus, there is one local minima on [0,2pi] at (3/2pi, pi), which cause f(x,y)=-2

Answer (score 1):

To do the second step you calculate the partial derivatives with respect to whatever variable is free on the boundary.  For example, if $x$ is oriented horizontally and $y$ is vertically, then to determine the critical points on the top of the square, calculate the partial wrt to $x$ evaluated at $y=0$.  Likewise for the botton, the partial wrt $x$ evaluated at $y=2\pi$.

Comment: I added at my initial post an other example at which apply the same method... Could you take a look at it??

Comment: A critical point is only required to find a maximum or minimum in the interior of a set. The principle is as follows: If the maximum exists on an interior of a set, than the gradient there is zero. However, the maximum may still be on the boundary. The same goes for the minimum. In fact, the minimum of your function is -1 and the maximum is 1, both of which occur on the boundary. So you can check the values at critical points on the interior of a set, but you must still always check the boundaries to see if the values are greater or less than there.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 2. (only)

$f(x,y)=\sin x+\cos y.$ One has $\partial U=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ with
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=&\left\{ (x,0):0\leq x\leq 2\pi \right\}  \\
B &=&\left\{ (2\pi ,y):0\leq y\leq 2\pi \right\}  \\
C &=&\left\{ (x,2\pi ):0\leq x\leq 2\pi \right\}  \\
D &=&\left\{ (0,y):0\leq y\leq 2\pi \right\} .
\end{eqnarray*}
We study the restriction of $f$ to each set $A,\ B,$ $C,$ and $D.$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{\mid A}(x,y) &=&f(x,0)=\sin x+\cos 0=\sin x+1,\ \ \ with\ \ \ 0\leq x\leq
2\pi . \\
\max_{A}f(x,y) &=&\max_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi }\sin x+1=1+1=2.
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{\mid B}(x,y) &=&f(2\pi ,y)=\sin 2\pi +\cos y=\cos y,\ \ \ with\ \ \ 0\leq
y\leq 2\pi . \\
\max_{B}f(x,y) &=&\max_{0\leq y\leq 2\pi }\cos y=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{\mid C}(x,y) &=&f(x,2\pi )=\sin x+\cos 2\pi =\sin x+1,\ \ \ with\ \ \
0\leq x\leq 2\pi . \\
\max_{C}f(x,y) &=&\max_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi }\sin x+1=1+1=2.
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{\mid D}(x,y) &=&f(0,y)=\sin 0+\cos y=\cos y,\ \ \ with\ \ \ 0\leq y\leq
2\pi . \\
\max_{D}f(x,y) &=&\max_{0\leq y\leq 2\pi }\cos y=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{\partial U}f(x,y) &=&\max \{\max_{A}f(x,y),\ \max_{B}f(x,y),\
\max_{C}f(x,y),\ \max_{D}f(x,y)\} \\
&=&\max \{2,\ 1,\ 2,\ 1\} \\
&=&2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I added at my initial post an other example at which apply the same method... Could you take a look at it??

Comment: OK, I will replay in a moment.

Comment: I am sorry, you are wrong. I will write you some explanations, give me 10 minutes I need to write in LATEX!

Answer (score 0):

For the local minimas obtained, chack the one that has the lowest value.

Comment: Could ou take a look at the edit part of my initial post??

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 2. And some warnings.

$f(x,y)=xy.$ One has $\partial U=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ with
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=&\left\{ (x,-1):-1\leq x\leq 1\right\} \\
B &=&\left\{ (1,y):-1\leq y\leq 1\right\} \\
C &=&\left\{ (x,1):-1\leq x\leq 1\right\} \\
D &=&\left\{ (-1,y):-1\leq y\leq 1\right\} .
\end{eqnarray*}
We study the restriction of $f$ to each set $A,\ B,$ $C,$ and $D.$
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid A}(x,y)=f(x,-)=-x=g(x),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq x\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The\ function$\ g\ $is\ clearly$\ $decreasing then $\max_{A}f(x,y)=\max%
\limits_{y\in \left[ -1,1\right] }g(x)=g(-1)=-(-1)=1.$
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid B}(x,y)=f(1,y)=y=h(y),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq y\leq 1.
\end{equation*}%
The\ function$\ h\ $is\ clearly\ increasing then $\max\limits_{B}f(x,y)=\max%
\limits_{y\in \left[ -1,1\right] }h(y)=h(1)=1.$%
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid C}(x,y)=f(x,1)=x\cdot 1=x=h(x),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq x\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The\ function$\ h\ $(the same as for the side $B$) is\ increasing then $%
\max\limits_{C}f(x,y)=\max\limits_{x\in \left[ -1,1\right] }h(x)=h(1)=1.$%
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid D}(x,y)=f(-1,y)=-y=g(y),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq y\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The\ function$\ g\ $(the same as for the side $A$)$\ is$ decreasing then $%
\max_{D}f(x,y)=\max\limits_{y\in \left[ -1,1\right] }g(x)=g(-1)=-(-1)=1.$

Now we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{\partial U}f(x,y) &=&\max \{\max_{A}f(x,y),\ \max_{B}f(x,y),\
\max_{C}f(x,y),\ \max_{D}f(x,y)\} \\
&=&\max \{1,\ 1,\ 1,\ 1\} \\
&=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}

WARNING: If seems to me that you think that a differentiable function say $%
g(t)$ defined for $t\in \left[ a,b\right] $ admits an extremum at $t_{0}$ if
and only if $g^{\prime }(t_{0})=0.$ THIS\ IS\ FALSE!

WHAT\ IS\ INSTEAD\ TRUE IS the following assertions:

1. If $g$ admits an extremum at $t_{0}\in (a,b)$ then $g^{\prime }(t_{0})=0.$
2. The converse of 1. above is false: That is to say, if $t_{0}\in (a,b)$ is
   such that $g^{\prime }(t_{0})=0$ then you can not say that $g$ admits an
   extremum at $t_{0}.$ Consider for instance $g(x)=x^{3}$ and $\left[ a,b%
   \right] =[-1,1].$ One has $g^{\prime }(0)=2\cdot 0^{2}=0,$ but the function $%
   g$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ and admits no extremum at $t_{0}=0.$
3. If $g$ admits an extremum at $t_{0}\in [a,b]$ (be careful, this
   set $[a,b]$ is closed on both sides) then either $t_{0}=a$ or $t_{0}=b$ or $%
   t_{0}\in (a,b)$ and in this last case one should have $g^{\prime }(t_{0})=0.$
   So if $g^{\prime }(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in (a,b)$ then it does not mean that
   there is no extremum of $g$, because this one can be $at$ $a$ or at $b.$ It
   is the case of our function above $g(x)=-x$ on $[-1,1].$ One has $g^{\prime
   }(x)=-1\neq 0$ for all $x\in \left[ -1,1\right] $ but $g$ admits a maximum
   at $x=-1$ and a minimum at $x=+1.$

Comment: YOUR First and third steps are OK. For the fourth step note that you have more than one value  f(0,0) you have also those on the boundary of U, those studied in the second step. So between 0=f(0,0) and the maximums on the boundary you conclude that the max of  f is on the boundary at one of the points of the second step. For the minimum the same method works.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Do we not look for them critical points on the boundary at the second step and not for the extremas??

Answer (score 0):

The second step is:

'2. Find the critical points of f, when we look at it as a function that is
defined only at $U$.

I agree with you that the question asks to find the critical points on the
boundary of $U$ only! However, why do we do this step? Why do we look for those
critical points? Answer, because we are going to check our maximum (and min)
among them in a further step. I did a shortcut. So, now i will answer the exact questions (with no shortcuts). I
will re-write my answer as follows.

$\bf{STEP 2.}$ $f(x,y)=xy.$ One has $\partial U=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ with
\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=&\left\{ (x,-1):-1\leq x\leq 1\right\}  \\
B &=&\left\{ (1,y):-1\leq y\leq 1\right\}  \\
C &=&\left\{ (x,1):-1\leq x\leq 1\right\}  \\
D &=&\left\{ (-1,y):-1\leq y\leq 1\right\} .
\end{eqnarray*}
We study the restriction of $f$ to each set $A,\ B,$ $C,$ and $D.$
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid A}(x,y)=f(x,-1)=-x=g(x),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq x\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The function $g$ is clearly decreasing ($g^{\prime }(x)=-1<0$ for all 
$x,\ -1\leq x\leq 1.$ Then, critical points of $f$ on the side $A$ would be
the two extremities $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,-1).$ [This means that if $f$ admits a
maximum or a minimum as a function defined on the segment $A$ (only) it would
be necessary at these two points.]

Now, let's go to the side $B.$ One has

\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid B}(x,y)=f(1,y)=y=h(y),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq y\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The function $ h$ is clearly increasing ($h^{\prime }(y)=1$ for all $y$
such that $-1\leq y\leq 1.$ Then, critical points of $f$ on the side $B$
would be the two extremities of the side $B,$ $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1).$ [This
means that if $f$ admits a maximum or a minimum as a function defined on the
segment $B$ (only) it would be necessary at these two points.]

Now, let's go to the side $C.$ One has
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid C}(x,y)=f(x,1)=x\cdot 1=x=h(x),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq x\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The function $h$ is clearly increasing ($h^{\prime }(x)=1$ for all $x$
such that $-1\leq x\leq 1.$ Then, critical points of $f$ on the side $C$
would be the two extremities of the side $C,$ $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1).$ [This
means that if $f$ admits a maximum or a minimum as a function defined on the
segment $C$ (only) it would be necessary at these two points.]

At last, let's go to the side $D.$ One has
\begin{equation*}
f_{\mid D}(x,y)=f(-1,y)=-y=g(y),\ \ \ with\ \ \ -1\leq y\leq 1.
\end{equation*}
The function $g$ is clearly decreasing ($g^{\prime }(y)=-1<0$ for all $y
$ such that $-1\leq y\leq 1.$ Then, critical points of $f$ on the side $D$
would be the two extremities of the side $D,$ $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,1).$ [This
means that if $f$ admits a maximum or a minimum as a function defined on the
segment $D$ (only) it would be necessary at these two points.] END OF
STEP 2.

$\bf{STEP 3.}$ Now we have to find max and min of $f$ on the whole set $U$
including its boundary $\partial U.$ The list of critical points on this
whole set is
\begin{eqnarray*}
intU &\rightarrow &(0,0),\ and\ f(0,0)=0. \\
A &\rightarrow &(-1,-1)\ and\ (1,-1):f(-1,-1)=1\ and\ f(1,-1)=-1.\  \\
B &\rightarrow &(1,-1)\ and\ (1,1):f(1,-1)=-1\ and\ f(1,1)=1. \\
C &\rightarrow &(-1,1)\ and\ (1,1):f(-1,1)=-1\ and\ f(1,1)=1. \\
D &\rightarrow &(-1,-1)\ and\ (-1,1):f(-1,-1)=1\ and\ f(-1,1)=-1.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that the values of $f$ on these critical points are
\begin{equation*}
-1=f(1,-1)=f(-1,1),\ 0=f(0,0),\ and\text{ }1=f(-1,-1)=f(1,1).
\end{equation*}

$\bf{STEP 4.}$ Now to find the maximum of $f$ on the closed square $intU\cup
\partial U=\left[ -1,1\right] \times \left[ -1,1\right] ,$ it suffices to
pick up the point where $f$ takes its maximum value among the above list of
critical points.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{\left[ -1,1\right] \times \left[ -1,1\right] }f(x,y) &=&\max
\{f(0,0),\ f(-1,-1),\ f(1,-1),\ f(1,1),\ f(-1,1)\} \\
&=&\max \{0,\ 1,\ -1,\ 1,\ -1\} \\
&=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}
The maximum value is obtained at two points $1=f(-1,-1)=f(1,1).$

Now to find the minimum of $f$ on the closed square $intU\cup \partial U=%
\left[ -1,1\right] \times \left[ -1,1\right] ,$ it suffices to pick up the
point(s) where $f$ takes its minimum value among the above list of critical
points.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\min_{\left[ -1,1\right] \times \left[ -1,1\right] }f(x,y) &=&\min
\{f(0,0),\ f(-1,-1),\ f(1,-1),\ f(1,1),\ f(-1,1)\} \\
&=&\min \{0,\ 1,\ -1,\ 1,\ -1\} \\
&=&-1.
\end{eqnarray*}
The minimum value is obtained at two points $-1=f(1,-1)=f(-1,1).$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic in both variables the values taken by $f$ on the given square are the same as the values taken by $f$ on all of ${\mathbb R}^2$. As any point $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ îs an interior point extremal values are taken at the zeros of $\nabla f$, of which there are four  per fundamental square (you have determined them). Comparing the values assumed by $f$ in these points one finds that $$\max_{(x,y)\in[0,2\pi]^2} f(x,y)=\max_{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2} f(x,y)=f\left({\pi\over2},0\right)=2\ ,$$
and similarly
$$\min_{(x,y)\in[0,2\pi]^2} f(x,y)=\min_{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2} f(x,y)=-2\ ,$$
as could have been found out by inspection of  the definition of $f$ right from the start.